# How to reset filtering in AutoCompleteTextView connected to ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I'm struggling with automatic filtering in AutoCompleteTextView.
In short, I have 2 different AutoCompleteTextViews set to the same ArrayAdapter.

Now, when I select an item by typing and filtering in AutoComplete, and jump to the second AutoComplete and click on it, it shows me only those items that were filtered in the previous AutoComplete.

```
            ...
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterMesta;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListMesta = new ArrayList<>();
        ...

        mMestoIstovara_autotext = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.editMestoIstovara);
        mMestoUtovara_atuotext = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.editMestoUtovara);
        ....

        JSONArray jsonArrayFirmeMesta = new JSONArray(Utility.getPrefsValue(this, Constants.SHAREDPREFS_SIFARNIK_MESTA));

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayFirmeMesta.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayFirmeMesta.getJSONObject(i);
            String client = jsonObject.getString("client");
            String mesto = jsonObject.getString("place");

            if (!arrayListFirme.contains(client))
                arrayListFirme.add(client);

            if (!arrayListMesta.contains(mesto))
                arrayListMesta.add(mesto);
        }

        arrayAdapterFirme = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayListFirme);
        arrayAdapterMesta = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayListMesta);


        if (mMestoIstovara_autotext != null) {

            mMestoIstovara_autotext.setAdapter(arrayAdapterMesta);
            mMestoIstovara_autotext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mMestoIstovara_autotext.showDropDown();
                }
            });

            mMestoIstovara_autotext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (mMestoIstovara_autotext.getText().length() > 0) {
                        mMestoIstovara_autotext.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                        mMestoIstovara_autotext.setText(mMestoIstovara_autotext.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                    } else
                        mMestoIstovara_autotext.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                }
            });
        }


        if (mMestoUtovara_atuotext != null) {
            //arrayAdapterMestoUtovara = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getStringArray(jsonMestoUtovara));
            mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setAdapter(arrayAdapterMesta);
            mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mMestoUtovara_atuotext.showDropDown();
                }
            });

            mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (mMestoUtovara_atuotext.getText().length() > 0) {
                        mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                        mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setText(mMestoUtovara_atuotext.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                    } else
                        mMestoUtovara_atuotext.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: this is normal behavior, you need two adapters

Comment: @pskink thanks, I solved this with two different adapters.